# How can I resolve a failed pipeline run with Bad Request of a subsequent run to a Traffic Manager + AppGW + App Service?

Tags: dns

I am using a configuration that has Traffic Manager + App Gateway + App Service and everything ran once successfully. I then run the pipeline with only code changes or changes to the app service and get the following error in the pipeline:

```
"ErrorEntity": {
                            "Code": "BadRequest", 
                            "ExtendedCode": "52011", 
                            "Message": "The traffic manager domain (ceel-test-operator.trafficmanager.net) can be removed only through the Traffic Manager.", 
                            "MessageTemplate": "The traffic manager domain ({0}) can be removed only through the Traffic Manager.", 
                            "Parameters": [
                                "ceel-test-operator.trafficmanager.net"
                            ]
                        }
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

This specific error is happening due to a limitation in azure and how each of these offerings have to be set up. For the TM + APPGW + APP Service pattern to work for externally facing sites, and get custom dns that flows all the way from TM to the App Service, you have to add the app services directly to the traffic manager first so that they get the traffic manager dns name is given to them, then you run traffic manager again with the final state of the app gateways being the end points and the app service array being empty. This sets the whole configuration up successfully because azure doesn't clean up the traffic manager name from the app service even though it's only indirectly related now.

**Why**

The subsequent pipeline run fails because when you try to modify the app service, it notices the traffic manager name on there but can't "fix" itself, only the traffic manager can do that.

**Resolution**

The only way to resolve this error is to delete the app services and re-create from the pipeline, all the end-points should set up correctly again.